# How to take a screenshot of a whole desktop with app menu selection?

Tags: screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a whole desktop with Applications Menu selection.How to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot > Grab the whole desktop > Grab after a delay of : 5 seconds (say)

[image]

- Do your Applications menu selection. Wait.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it *is* possible to do it without the delay, but with some hacks instead. I have written a small script which will allow you to do that without the delay. This is a big hack, but it works and is certainly (for me) more preferable than using the delay.

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################################################
# Simple script to enable users to make screenshots of tooltips/menus/etc...         # 
# without timers                                                                     #
######################################################################################

######################################################################################
# Configuration Section (defaults)                                                   #
######################################################################################
SCREENSHOT_COMMAND="shutter -s"

# The keys can be found out using xinput test "keyboard name"
MODIFIER_KEY=133 #The <Super> Key (aka. Meta or Windows Key)f
CANCEL_KEY=54 # C
CAPTURE_KEY=27 # R

DAEMON_MODE="false" # change to true if you want to keep the script running after the screenshot was taken
VERBOSE="true" #Change this to any value if you dont want to have notifications

######################################################################################

######################################################################################
# Command parsing                                                                    #
######################################################################################

function usage {
    echo "$0 [-hemrcdn]"
    echo "-h prints this message"
    echo "-e <command> - execute that command instead of shutter"
    echo "-m <int> - The modifier key to use. Use xinput test <keyboar> to find out what is what"
    echo "-r <int> - The key to use for capture."
    echo "-c <int> - The key used for cancelling (only valid in non daemon mode)"
    echo "-d - daemon mode. Will keep on running after a screenshot was taken. to kill the daemon, use \"killall xinput\""
    echo "-n - disables notifications"
    exit;
}

while getopts "he:m:r:c:dn" flag
do
    if [ "$flag" == "h" ]; then
        usage
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "e" ]; then
        SCREENSHOT_COMMAND=$OPTARG
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "m" ]; then
        CAPTURE_KEY=$OPTARG
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "r" ]; then
        SCREENSHOT_COMMAND=$OPTARG
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "c" ]; then
        CANCEL_KEY=$OPTARG
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "d" ]; then
        DAEMON_MODE="true"
    fi
    if [ "$flag" == "n" ]; then
        VERBOSE="false"
    fi
done

######################################################################################

KEYBOARDS=`xinput list | grep "slave" | grep "keyboard" | sed "s/[^a-zA-Z]*\(.*\)id=.*/\1/" | sed "s/[\t ]*$//"`

function run {
    MODIFIER_PRESSED="false"
    while read line;
    do
        COMMAND=`echo $line | awk '{print $2;}'`
        KEY=`echo $line | awk '{print $3;}'`
        if [ "$KEY" == "$MODIFIER_KEY" ]; then
            if [ "$COMMAND" == "press" ]; then
                MODIFIER_PRESSED="true"
            else 
                MODIFIER_PRESSED="false"
            fi
        fi 
        if [ "$KEY" == "$CAPTURE_KEY" -a "$MODIFIER_PRESSED" == "true" -a "$COMMAND" == "press" ]; then
            bash -c $SCREENSHOT_COMMAND
            if [ "$VERBOSE" == "true" ]; then
                notify-send "Taking Screenshot"     
            fi
            if [ "$DAEMON_MODE" == "false" ]; then
                quit
            fi
        fi
        if [ "$KEY" == "$CANCEL_KEY" -a "$MODIFIER_PRESSED" == "true" -a "$COMMAND" == "press" -a "$DAEMON_MODE" == "false" ]; then
            if [ "$VERBOSE" == "true" ]; then   
                notify-send "Canceling Screenshot"
            fi
            quit
        fi
    done;
}

function quit {
    killall -9 xinput
    exit
}

if [ "$VERBOSE" == "true" ]; then
    notify-send "Screenshot script waiting. Press Meta + R to capture the screenshot"
fi
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $KEYBOARDS
do
    unbuffer xinput test "$i" | run & 
done
```

Before you can actually use the script (on ubuntu), you need to make sure you have *xinput* and *unbuffer*. To do that simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install xinput expect-dev
```

Then you can run the script. Run it first with the -h option to see the possible configuration options. By default, the script will only work once and you have to restart the script after every screenshot (e.g. by a keyboard shortcut). This is because the script might have a performance inpact. If you want to run it as a "daemon" run it with the `-d` option.

By default it will also use shutter. If you want to use something else, use the `-e` option, e.g. `script.sh -c "ksnapshot"`

By default, the capture button will be <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. you can change that with the configuration options.

Answer (score 4):

*Since you were wondering if it was also possible with Shutter...*

To do it in [[image: Shutter icon] **Shutter**](http://shutter-project.org/), open it up and select **Full Screen** from either the toolbar or from **File** > **New** > **Fullscreen**.

Make sure you have a time delay set so you have enough time to open the Applications menu (**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Main** tab; at the bottom, there is an selection box: **Capture after a delay of __ seconds**).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Open screenshot, and set a delay of whatever time you think is necessary to go back and open the menu.  Keep it open until the shot is taken.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Fast answer / workaround

<sup>(*for medium to advanced ubuntu users*)</sup>

- Add a custom shortcut to the following command:
  `gnome-screenshot --delay=numIntValueInSecs`
  ***for example***
  `gnome-screenshot --delay=3`
- Add another one to take active window screenshots:
  `gnome-screenshot -w --delay=3`

  *That's it*, **but** I'd also recommend setting 2 others 
  that would give you more time to navigate deeper in menus.

  - `gnome-screenshot --delay=10`
  - `gnome-screenshot -w --delay=10`

  [image]

## Elaborate answer

<sup>(*novice to hacker*)</sup>

### Intro:

Whenever you press <kbd>PrntScr</kbd>, all Ubuntu does is calling **`gnome-screenshot`** which is usually located on the `/usr/bin/` path and available from the "terminal" (teletype, tty, cli, command line/prompt), so you can use it in all sorts of ways to fit your funky purposes.

The `gnome-screenshot` little program accepts optional parameters, you can see all options by passing the standard parameter to ask for help, you know the one (`-h`)

[image]

If you're still not sure how to use this, you can always read a more detailed help, just ask for the manual typing `man gnome-screenshot`

[image]

The more you read full manuals, hacking ubuntu to fit your needs will become intuitive and you won't need other people to give you step by step instructions.
Maybe by this point you even know how to make this workaround by yourself, if you're still lost (hopefully not), just keep reading...

### Instructions:

- Step Zero: Open Ubuntu's system settings and navigate to the Keyboard option:

[image]

**Now**

1. Navigate to `Shortcuts` tab.
2. Select `Custom Shortcuts`
3. Hit the `+` button to add your new custom shortcut.
4. Give a name and a command.
   <sup>(just like described on the ***"Fast Answer"*** above)</sup>
   **4½.** Assign the key combination you'd like.
5. Close this window or it wont work.

[image]

***presto!

You just took one further step to be an ubuntu master, I hope this answer was helpful ***

Comment: Nice! I like the idea of set a default delay for the screenshot fired with the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, in the end it happens to have a few more use cases than just taking screenshots of dropdown menus.

Answer (score 1):

Use Screenshot (in accesssories) and set 'Grab after a delay of xx seconds'.

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this, not an actual solution.

Open the `Screenshot` application, in the opened window, set a time as **Grab after a delay of x seconds**.

#### Note: This cannot be used for grabing a specific portion of the window.

Note: Sorry, It is not also possible to take the screenshot of **Screenshot** application itself as a Window or grabing a specific portion.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a bug. It's possible to use the "Screenshot" tool and set "Grab after a delay of x seconds" to the time you need to get the menu back open.

Answer (score 0):

xfce:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -w -d 5
```

`-d, --delay` Delay in seconds before taking the screenshot

`-w, --window` Take a screenshot of the active window