# taking screenshot with menu activated using keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

Taking a screen shot pressing <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key will not work if I have the application menu activated or a pop-up menu (right-click).

I know it s possible to do that [using a delay on the screen shot application](https://askubuntu.com/a/15641/28076), but sometimes it would be a lot better to use a keyboard shortcut to do that.

Does anyone know if it is possible to take those screen shots using <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key (or some other shortcut)?

Comment: Using `scrot` instead of the keyboard shortcut works. See [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410609/8822).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, I found out this is a [*won't fix* bug described in Gnome's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100903).

So the only way to do it is use the screen shot tool with a delay, as [described before](https://askubuntu.com/a/15641/28076).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will this be improved?

Comment: @CasperLi I don't think things will change. It has been reported as *won't fix* at the GNOME project... :-(

Comment: but it is so inconvenient...

Answer (score 1):

The standard screenshot application `gnome-panel-screenshot` application supports a `--delay` argument (amongst others).

For a full list, run at a terminal

`gnome-panel-screenshot --help`

Edit : D'oh, you already know about that.

You can use the `Keyboard` settings panel to define custom shortcuts to commands - including arguments.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 15.04, the command is now `gnome-screenshot`

Answer (score 1):

There is also delayed screenshot feature in Gimp:

Click "File" -> "Create" -> "Screenshot..."

It will take screenshot of only menu itself if you choose "Take screenshot of a single window" and focus menu.

Need to take screenshot for entire screen or region to capture window with menu open, and then crop.

Answer (score 1):

## 2023

As these answers are quite old and the build in screenshot tool (from gnome) does not have the timeout option anymore, [Shutter](https://shutter-project.org/) does the job for me. It comes with an Editor (e.g. blur something) and also supports delay and even **special commands to capture a menus.**

To replace the standard hotkey (prt sc), see: https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/issues/631