# When I create a screenshot, the menus do not appear

Tags: screenshot, shutter, print-screen, gnome-screenshot

I tried to capture the screen of my desktop in Ubuntu but when I try to do it in these two ways the drop down menus do not appear in the capture only the windows appear and the desktop menus do not capture them.

The first photo I took as an example of someone else I can not capture the screen this way

[image: I can not take a catch like this]

[image: Captures the desktop and windows but the drop-down menus do not]

Why is this happening to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393542/screenshot-printscreen-doesnt-work-with-menus-dropped-down?rq=1).

ScreenShot/PrintScreen doesn't work with menus dropped down!