# Volume bar reaching maximum sound level prematurely (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sound, 20.04

My volume bar isn't using the entire range to adjust the sound level. For instance, at this position I have maximum volume:

[image]

When it's at 0 I get no sound, which is fine.

Is there an easy fix?

Ps: I am using a wireless headphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed it can be fixed on sound configurations, setting to option (**S/PDIF)** instead of the standard:

[image]

(I can't post a print of the menu options because of another [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393542/screenshot-printscreen-doesnt-work-with-menus-dropped-down) on Ubuntu... )