# How to take screenshot while a menu is open

Tags: screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take a screenshot of a whole desktop with app menu selection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15639/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-desktop-with-app-menu-selection)

I recently wanted to take a screen shot of a nautilus menu to provide an image to the [answer of a nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/79266/61218) related question. *(I was looking for it)*.

But when I opened up the menu and press the `prtsrc` key, nothing happened. I have also tried `Shift+PrtSrc` Key and `Alt+PrtScr` key. Result was the same.

My question is : Is is not possible not take a screenshot while you have a menu open?. Is it bug or not?

Note: To test this, just right-click on the desktop, and press `prtsrc` key.