# Empathy doesn't show properly on indicator menu (12.10)

Tags: indicator, empathy

Whenever I get a message on Facebook or gtalk, a bubble pops in the upper right corner, and I hear a sound. But, the message icon doesn't turn blue, and no "new messages" or such is displayed.

Besides, status in the indicator is always at "disconnected"

http://i46.tinypic.com/8wxk76.png "A message just arrived, the indicator didn't turn blue, and no messages are waiting. Besides, empathy stands Desconectado"

Comment: Could you upload a [screen-shoot](http://askubuntu.com/q/15639/62483)?

Comment: OK, i uploaded it